# How to filter items based on a hashmap value in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following structure:

Here, 'subjects' is an array of hashmap

[image: structure of firestore database document]

Now, I want to find all the documents having id = 1 in my collection.

**Student collection class:**

```
    String name;
    String div;
    String phoneNumber;
    ArrayList<SubjectInStudentModel> subjects=new ArrayList<>();
```

**SubjectInStudent class:**

```
    int id;
    ArrayList<String> dates=new ArrayList<String>();
```

**What I've Tried So Far:**

`db.collection("student").whereEqualTo("subjects.id", subjectId).get()`

it returns empty document set. I think since there are multiple hashmaps and not one, this query fails.

```
Map<String,Integer> test = new HashMap<>();
test.put("id",subjectId);
db.collection("student").whereArrayContains("subjects", test).get()
```

This works when there are not 'dates' in the hashmap.

Similarly, the below codes work when dates are null

```
SubjectInStudentModel subjectInStudentModel = new SubjectInStudentModel();
subjectInStudentModel.setDates(new ArrayList<String>());
subjectInStudentModel.setId(subjectId);
db.collection("student").whereArrayContains("subjects", subjectInStudentModel).get()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AlexMamo I've updated the question to add more information about the structure and what I tried.

Comment: I tried similar method,

Map<String,Integer> test = new HashMap<>();
test.put("id",subjectId);
db.collection("student").whereArrayContains("subjects", test).get() 

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `arrayContains` operator checks if an *entire* object already exists in the array, so both the ID and the dates. It cannot check for just a single property of that object.

To make the current check work, you'll need to pass in an object with all the data for the subject.

Alternatively, you can create an additional field where you keep only the IDs of each subject (e.g. `subjectIDs`) and then use `arrayContains` on that.